# Unlink after force download not working Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i was unable to remove my file after force download.below is the code

```
public function download($id)
{
 $this->load->helper('download');
    $filepath = "url/" . $id;
    force_download("file-name", $filepath);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    unlink($filepath);

}
```

Kindly update me on this regard.

Comment: My question: how can I check if the file was downloaded and saved?

Comment: why you want to check it because force download will always download.so we can assume that file has been downloaded.

Answer (score 4):

I have came across same situation. So i just want to share the following information if that helps people in need.

Actually 
**force_download("file-name", $filepath);**
Nothing you have written after this piece of code will be executed, because force_download method has a **header** and an **exit** call.

So if you want to delete file which is being downloaded, you can delete it before calling **force_download** method.

Some people will be having a doubt like how can we delete a file before downloading it.Well actually the second parameter in force_download method is actually the content of the file being downloaded. Once you have that you do not require the file.

```
$file_content = file_get_contents($file_path); // Read the file's contents
if(file_exists($file_path)){
    unlink($file_path);
}
force_download($filename, $file_content);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_content = file_get_contents($file_path); // Read the file's contents
if(file_exists($file_path)){
    unlink($file_path);
}
force_download($filename, $file_content);
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Use `base_url()`  path for download the file and use `FCPATH` for unlink the file(absolute path to the file)

```
public function download($id)
    {
     $this->load->helper('download');
        $filepath = "url/" . $id;  // eg : base_url()."/".$id;
        force_download("file-name", $filepath);
    //    ignore_user_abort(true);
       $filepath2 = "url/" . $id;  // eg : FCPATH."/".$id;
        unlink();

    }
```

Comment: ignore_user_abort(true); won't work after force download

Answer (score 0):

Use  unlink('filename');,you will not use filepath only use filename.

Comment: i can give the file path also in unlink