# delete a file after download in codeigniter

Tags: php, file, download, codeigniter-3

I want to remove my file from downloads directory after a user has downloaded it. But it is not deleted. I am using Codeigniter download_helper for downloading the file.
Below is my code:

Controller

```
public function download($key,$id)
{
    $link=$this->article->download($key,$id);//get record from database via article model
    if(empty($link))
    {
        show_404(); 
    }
    force_download(DOWNLOADS_PATH.$link->file_name, NULL);//download file
    $this->article_lib->remove_downloaded($link->file_name);//user has downloaded so now delete this
}
```

Library

```
public function remove_downloaded($file_name)
{
   if(file_exists(DOWNLOADS_PATH.$file_name))
     {
      unlink(DOWNLOADS_PATH.$file_name);
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Be sure to check if you have the right permissions on the folder to be able to delete

Comment: @CAllen I have the permissions. If I place the unlink($file_name) before the force_download it deletes it.

Comment: Whats the error it gives if you put it after? I never had any problems with this before but I would suggest putting a sleep for like 1 second. Maybe it needs to finish download before you can delete it. I am assuming here.

Comment: @CAllen that's the problem force_download() returns void, so I can't check for error. Moreover, the file is downloaded but isn't deleted I don't get any errors I just get blank webpage..

Comment: sorry, i delteed the comment because, I saw that it wouldn't have help. I'll do a test here and let you know right now. What is the file extension are trying to delete?

Comment: maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921466/auto-delete-all-files-after-x-time) could help your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I was not reading, but the problem with your code is that it is missing the closing `)`

```
    public function remove_downloaded($file_name)
    {
       if(file_exists($file_name)) // here is the problem
         {
          unlink($file_name);
         }
    }
```

Also the way the force download works is that anything after will not run. I would suggest using an ajax call after the controller.

*UPDATE*:

But as you have mentioned in your comment, you can delete the file before creating it as mentioned in this post [Unlink after force download not working Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157589/unlink-after-force-download-not-working-codeigniter)

Comment: Updated the answer.. Please see answer above

Comment: No i just showed you where the typo was :) but the way you have done it is the right way, deleting it before you download it because in my test nothing runs after a force_download

Comment: No @CAllen deleting before the download was just to make sure that I had enough permissions if I delete it before download then what am I downloading?

Comment: ok then well my first option would be best. You will have ti use an ajax call after you download to delete it.

That is actually how I do it in my project. Just taht I don't use force_download option.

Comment: No problem. Glad I can be of assistance

Answer (score 2):

You can find out why it wont be deleted in `system/helpers/download_helper.php`, there is an exit, so all code you have after `force_download()` will never be executed.

```
//File:  system/helpers/download_helper.php
// From line 135
// Generate the server headers
header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.$filesize);
header('Cache-Control: private, no-transform, no-store, must-revalidate');

// If we have raw data - just dump it
if ($data !== NULL)
{
    exit($data);
}

// Flush 1MB chunks of data
while ( ! feof($fp) && ($data = fread($fp, 1048576)) !== FALSE)
{
    echo $data;
}

fclose($fp);
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `ignore_user_abort(true)` function (***[docs](http://php.net/function.ignore_user_abort)***) to solve this issue, and it worked for me.

Try below code,

```
public function download($key, $id)
{
    $link = $this->article->download($key, $id);//get record from database via article model
    if (empty($link)) {
        show_404();
    }

    force_download(DOWNLOADS_PATH . $link->file_name, NULL);//download file

    ignore_user_abort(true); // Set whether a client disconnect should abort script execution
    if (connection_aborted()) {
        $this->article_lib->remove_downloaded($link->file_name);//user has downloaded so now delete this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are deleting a file not the directory. if not sure
then try this. it will delete the file and directory also

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    $files=scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $file)
     if ($file != "." && $file != "..") rrmdir("$dir/$file");
    rmdir($dir);
}
else if (file_exists($dir)) unlink($dir);
}
```

Comment: I want to delete the file only else it will delete all download files as well as download dir.

Answer (score 0):

While downloading you are passing the full path of the file you want to download but while deleting it, i mean while unlinking it you are passing only filename.

So please do try:

```
public function download($key,$id)
{
    $link=$this->article->download($key,$id);//get record from database via article model
    if(empty($link))
    {
        show_404(); 
    }
    force_download(DOWNLOADS_PATH.$link->file_name, NULL);//download file
    $this->article_lib->remove_downloaded(DOWNLOADS_PATH.$link->file_name); //Included full path
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Real apologies that was a typo and I have corrected it in my question now

Comment: Oh, then need to think

Answer (score 0):

just replace in controller function

**this:**

```
$this->article_lib->remove_downloaded($link->file_name);
```

**with:**

```
$this->article_lib->remove_downloaded(DOWNLOADS_PATH.$link->file_name);
```

**or maybe with:**

```
$this->article->remove_downloaded(DOWNLOADS_PATH.$link->file_name);
```

Comment: Real apologies that was a typo and I have corrected it in my question now.

Comment: No. It does not go there lets say I echo 1; it does after the force_download its not shown in browser

Comment: @yaxe I read somewhere in a post that no code works after calling force_download function

Comment: may be we can force headers some how which will make it work thats what i am looking for.

Comment: @yaxe please check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32051196/6907728) might be of some help.

Comment: Try to use this function
public function download($fileName = NULL) {   
   if ($fileName) {
    $file = realpath ( "download" ) . "\\" . $fileName;
    // check file exists    
    if (file_exists ( $file )) {
     // get file content
     $data = file_get_contents ( $file );
     unlink($file);
     //force download
     force_download ( $fileName, $data );
    } else {
     // Redirect to base url
     redirect ( base_url () );
    }
   }
  }